For my Data Analysis on House Prices with GB, Tree, and Random Forest, my MSE is too high
I've tried using all the variables vs also selecting certain variables, however the MSE stays high. I'm wondering if its a mistake in my code instead. I'm also was trying to add some feature engineering but commented it out for now as it made my MSE worse.
 #kaggle : House Prices - Advanced Regression Techniques   
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import sklearn.model_selection
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import sklearn as sk
    import sklearn.tree
    import sklearn.ensemble
    
    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/andrewhashoush/Downloads/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/train.csv')
    df_test = pd.read_csv('/Users/andrewhashoush/Downloads/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/test.csv')
    
    print(df.head())
    print(df.info())
    
    #selected_features = ['OverallQual', 'YearBuilt', 'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', 'GrLivArea',
    #                     'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'MSZoning', 'Neighborhood',
    #                     'KitchenQual', 'CentralAir', 'LotArea', 'MSSubClass', 'LotFrontage', 
    #                     'Street', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'OverallCond', 'RoofStyle',
    #                     'RoofMatl', 'BsmtQual','SaleCondition', 'SaleType', 'YrSold', 'MoSold', 
    #                     'PoolArea']
    
    selected_features = [
        'LotFrontage', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'MasVnrArea', 'HalfBath',
        'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'GarageCars', 'WoodDeckSF',
        'OpenPorchSF', 'MoSold', 'YrSold', 'MSZoning', 'Alley',
        'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood',
        'Condition1', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'Exterior1st',
        'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation',
        'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2',
        'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir', 'Electrical', 'KitchenQual',
        'Functional', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual',
        'GarageCond', 'PavedDrive', 'PoolQC', 'Fence', 'MiscFeature',
        'SaleType', 'SaleCondition'
    ]
    
    #feature engineering
    #df['Quality_Condition'] = df['OverallQual'] * df['OverallCond']
    #df['Age_at_Sale'] = df['YrSold'] - df['YearBuilt']
    #selected_features += ['Quality_Condition', 'Age_at_Sale']
    
    X = df[selected_features]
    print(X.head())
    
    for column in X.columns:
        missing_data = df[column].isnull().sum()
        print(f"{column}: {missing_data}")
      
    categorical_vars = X.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist()
    numerical_vars = X.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns.tolist()
    
    print("Categorical Variables:", categorical_vars)
    print()
    print("Numerical Variables:", numerical_vars)
    
    
    #%%
    
    #filled the missing categorical values with mode
    for var in categorical_vars:
        mode_value = X[var].mode()[0] 
        # X[var] = X[var].fillna(mode_value) 
        # X.loc[:, var] = X.loc[:, var].fillna(mode_value)
        X.loc[:, var] = X[var].fillna(mode_value)
    
    #filled the missing numerical values with median
    for var in numerical_vars:
        median_value = X[var].median()
        X.loc[:, var] = X[var].fillna(median_value)
    
    #checking it
    for column in X.columns:
        missing_data = X[column].isnull().sum()
        print(f"{column}: {missing_data}")
    
    #one hot encoding 
    X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=categorical_vars)
    y = df['SalePrice']
    
    #split the data
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X,y, train_size =.8, random_state= 123)
    
    dt_model = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=5, random_state=123)
    dt_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = dt_model.predict(X_val)  
    mse_val = np.mean((y_pred - y_val)**2)
    print(f"MSE: {mse_val}")
    
    # Random Forest Regressor
    rf_model = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=123)
    rf_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred1 = rf_model.predict(X_val)
    mse_val1 = np.mean((y_pred1 - y_val)**2)
    print(f"MSE: {mse_val1}")
    
    # Gradient Boosting Regressor
    gb_model = sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1, random_state=123)
    gb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred2 = gb_model.predict(X_val)
    mse_val2 = np.mean((y_pred2 - y_val)**2)
    print(f"MSE: {mse_val2}")

MSE: 1451852149.6361678
MSE: 944388532.5714014
MSE: 755815420.2686024


It doesn't look like there are any obvious errors in your code.
It looks like you're trying to predict housing prices, though, based on the filepaths for the data you're working with. For this task, those are potentially reasonable MSE values.
MSE is mean squared error, so if you take the square root of it, you get root mean squared error. RMSE can be interpreted as more or less the average absolute value of the error in your predictions, while MSE is a little trickier to interpret, since MSE is measured in units that are the square of the target variable, while RMSE is measured in units equal to those of the target variable. If you take the square root of the MSE values you've provided, you get values between 27,000 and 39,000, which are not crazy - in other words, it means your models are off by about that much, on average. If you are predicting US house prices in dollars, that is a relatively reasonable range for your models to be off by.
More on RMSE vs MSE here
